# Error when creating indexes for flexible Cloud Datastore: Unexpected attribute 'indexes' for object of type AppInfoExternal

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sdk

When I access to the Cloud Datastore web management, there are no indexes listed under the "Indexes" section and I would like to define explicitly some indexes in order to run advanced queries.  I have a yaml file that looks like:

---

```js
indexes:
- kind: order
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: email
  - name: name
  - name: ownerId
  - name: status
  - name: updated_at
  - name: created_at
    direction: desc
```

And I run the following command to create the indexes:

> gcloud preview datastore create-indexes indexes.yaml

and this is the error message that I'm getting:

"Unexpected attribute 'indexes' for object of type AppInfoExternal"

Has anybody come across the same issue? Any ideas?

Regards,
Jose

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately the `create-indexes` command is a little brittle: it requires that the `index.yaml` file that you provide is named `index.yaml` and not `indexes.yaml`. Otherwise, it will try and parse it as a different type of configuration.

Try renaming your index file to `index.yaml` then calling the command again.

Comment: As a follow up -- we've filed this internally so we can get it fixed.

Comment: Tried creating the indexes again after renaming the yaml file to  `index.yaml` and it worked. Thanks